# AVSPEED iConf.net SDK Video Conferencing quality

Tags: video, sdk

after googling and spending a whole day in to this topic, i'm giving up and must ask you guys this question.
I'm installed AVSPEED iConf.net SDK Video Conferencing on 2 machines and trying to get a good conference between them with the server application.
First, i had run the ip2ip.exe and, no wonder, the quality and the connection was perfect.

When i'm going to start the application in help with the server application, i'm getting the connection, but there a big problems in sound, quality of the video, latency and this makes a conference impossible.

In the SourceCode of the Server can be changed a little bit, but all changes are not the right solution :(. How can i get a good Video Quality when i make this conference? I think the source code is correct, so it may be a computer problem? or a network problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are associated with the company in question, instead of flagging the question and complaining it makes you look bad, how about answering to provide some support to your user base?

Answer (score 1):

I use the iConf SDK through their central server and it works great for me - where is your central server running from ? what is the available bandwidth ? which codec do you use ? what is your video size? There are so many factors that can affect the performance of your conference through the central server. The fact that you are also complaining about the sound quality leads me to believe that there are underlying network, or configuration issues going on in your particular case

Comment: Hi Zach,
im using the h.263 codec, my video size is 352x288, my bitrate ~2000 (tried 1000 and 3000 too), my I-Frame frequency lower than 100 (tried 5-20 too), my available bandwith...i dont know exactly what you want to hear from me: download 16000kbit/s, upload 1024kbit/s ?

Thanks for the reply! ;)

Comment: H.263 is a low quality but lower bitrate codec so don't expect anything great from it -the SDK gives you a choice of H.264 and MPEG4 with higher bitrates - these will give you the quality that you are looking for.

Comment: well in my ip2ip test im using h.263 too and that quality is much better than the quality over the server... , h.264 give me a higher quality, but my partners may use umts and so i can not take a higher bitrate